# Can PouchDB proxy a big database on the client side?

Tags: architecture, frontend, pouchdb

Working on single page applications i have to write a lot of boilerplate code in order to synchronise with the server side data.

[PouchDB](http://pouchdb.com/) offers an elegant solution to this problem allowing to access the data locally on the client side.

What i don't understand, is whether Pouch is suitable as a database proxy or not, in cases when the database is too big to fully fit in the browser memory.

As far as i can read, Pouch works duplicating a whole remote database, and thus can be used just in those cases when the whole database fits in the browser memory.

#### Example use case

Let's say that i have a database with all Wikipedia articles and i want to manipulate part of them on the client side. Replication is not the way to go, what is needed is proxing. For example when a query is issued locally in the client side, just the matching results should be transferred. It is not feasible to run a query just on the replicated values, because it is not possible to replicate the whole database locally.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're right that PouchDB sync wouldn't really do what you want it to do. It's designed to sync entire databases, or predefined subsets of a database using server-side design docs.

If I were you, I would probably still use PouchDB, but I would handle the syncing manually.  Something like this:

```
var localDB = new PouchDB('localDB');
var remoteDB = new PouchDB('http://some-site.com:5984/somedb');

function searchForDocs(docId) {
  // try the local DB first
  localDB.get(docId).catch(function (err) {
    if (err.name !== 'not_found') {
      throw error;
    }
    // not found, so fall back to the remote DB
    return remoteDB.get(docId).then(function (doc) {
      // cache in the local DB
      delete doc._rev;
      return localDB.put(doc).then(function () {
        return doc;
      });
    });
  }).then(function (doc) {
    // do something with our doc
  }).catch(function (err) {
    // handle any errors along the way
  });
}
```

Using `get()` is a little simplistic here; in your Wikipedia case you would probably want to do `allDocs({startkey: query, endkey: query + '\uffff'})` to find all docs whose ID start with a query. Or you could use a secondary index.

So although you wouldn't be getting the benefits of PouchDB's built-in sync, you are getting the benefits of being able to write the same code against the server as the client, plus PouchDB's cross-browser support. So I don't think this is a bad way to go about it.

Comment: Interesting. This way, looks easy to write a caching wrapper. The problem i see here is that cached reports would not be automatically kept in sync with the remote, so the cache cannot be trusted

Comment: Yeah, it is unfortunate, but you'd have to handle that manually. For instance, you could just set up a `changes()` listener on the remote database and look for IDs that match the ID of a doc you've already cached to see when it gets updated. Sounds like a good idea for a PouchDB plugin. :)

Comment: Coming soon in CouchDb 2.x is support for changes() on indexed views that will allow more efficient filtered changes and filtered replication.